# ExtJS 4 Store's filterBy() affect only first page when pagingmemory proxy is used

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid and its store configured with [`Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy), like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    data: myData,
    fields: storeFields,
    proxy: {
        type: 'pagingmemory',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            getData: function(rawData) {
                ...
            },
        }
    },
    remoteFilter: true,
    remoteSort: true
});
```

When I want to filter store locally I use either [`filter()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) or [`filterBy()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy).

When I use `filter()` full set of data is filtered (passed via `data: myData`), but when I use `filterBy()` its only affect first page.

**Is it possible to apply a `filterBy()` to the entire data set in similar way with `filter()` when `pagingmemory` proxy is used?**

*I understand that `pagingmemory` proxy use two stores to save the entire data and data to be used in grid store, and I understand that it is possible to rewrite `filterBy()` work, but perhaps there is some simple solution?*

Comment: You may want to have a look at memory proxy in the later versions, it includes this functionality and it's more robust, you could look at back-porting it.

Comment: You want me to try move ExtJS 5+ pagingmemory proxy to my ExtJS 4 project? Ok, thx, all try.